# Suspense fallback same as lazy load children

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lazy-loading, react-suspense

```
Const A = lazy(() => import(“compA”))


render() {
    <Suspense fallback={<B/>}
          <A>
             <B />
          </A>
    </Suspense>

}
```

I want B to be loaded while A is resolving. But fallback unmounts B and is mounted again when A resolves.

I've tried useRef and useMemo hooks for component B, but that still does not resolve the issue.
How can I achieve not remounting the component B when A resolves in above scenario?

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. This is how react works. If it encounters new component while diffing, it will unmount the old node and all its children and will mount the new node.

- Your old VDOM is: `<B />`
- New VDOM is: `<A><B /></A>`

This is what it does:

1. The old one was `B`, the new one is `A`
2. it compares them. They are not same
3. Unmounts `B` (and all its children if exist)
4. Mounts `A`
5. Then mounts its children (`B`)

What you can do is to move the visual part of the B component and use it as the fallback, so the re-mounting wont cause any issues

Comment: What do you mean by visual part of a component?

Comment: @macro I mean without the logic. Create new component similar to B, without the logic, so the re-mounting wont cause any issues